# Electron: Cannot access dialog before initialization

Tags: electron

I have a renderer file that has the sole purpose of opening a dialog box to select files from. I have tried rewriting this so many times, and each time I get a different error. What am I doing wrong?

Exact code:

```
const { ipcRenderer, shell, remote } = require('electron')
const dialog = remote.dialog;

function openFileBrowser() {

    dialog.showOpenDialog(remote.getCurrentWindow(), {
        properties: ["openFile", "multiSelections"]
    }).then(result => {
        if (result.canceled === false) {
            console.log("Selected file paths:")
            console.log(result.filePaths)
        }
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
    })
}
```

Related HTML:

```
        <div id="button-container">
            <nav>
                <ul class="buttons">
                    <li id="Open" onclick="openFileBrowser()">Proxies</li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
```

Error Code

```
renderer.js:37 Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'dialog' before initialization
    at openFileBrowser (renderer.js:37)
    at HTMLLIElement.onclick (proxies.html:16)
```

Using Electron:
"7.1.7"

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include the exact error you're getting and a complete, but minimal (!) code example to reproduce the issue. Please also state the Electron version you're using.

Comment: I have edited the original message, I apologize for the lack of clarity.

Comment: Please add a complete example, i.e. not just excerpts. Your example should me as small as possible while also exposing the error. Oftentimes, it makes sense to make a copy of the project and remove everything that isn't necessary for the error to occur. That would be a [mcve].

Comment: @snwflk Made a new project, tried to reproduce the issue and I can't. This is incredibly frustrating. I will try to post my answer when I find it.

Answer (score 1):

Since Electron 6.0.0, the functions [`dialog.showMessageBox()`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/dialog#dialogshowmessageboxbrowserwindow-options), [`dialog.showOpenDialog()`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/dialog#dialogshowopendialogbrowserwindow-options) and [`dialog.showSaveDialog()`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/dialog#dialogshowsavedialogbrowserwindow-options) return Promises and no longer take callback functions.

There are synchronous counterparts [`dialog.showMessageBoxSync()`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/dialog#dialogshowmessageboxsyncbrowserwindow-options), [`dialog.showOpenDialogSync()`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/dialog#dialogshowopendialogsyncbrowserwindow-options) and [`dialog.showSaveDialogSync()`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/dialog#dialogshowsavedialogsyncbrowserwindow-options).

Check out the following code examples showing the asynchronous and the synchronous way of displaying an open dialog:

### Asynchronous: `dialog.showOpenDialog()`

```js
const remote = require("electron").remote
const dialog = remote.dialog

dialog.showOpenDialog(remote.getCurrentWindow(), {
    properties: ["openFile", "multiSelections"]
}).then(result => {
    if (result.canceled === false) {
        console.log("Selected file paths:")
        console.log(result.filePaths)
    }
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
})
```

### Synchronous: `dialog.showOpenDialogSync()`

```js
const remote = require("electron").remote
const dialog = remote.dialog

let result = dialog.showOpenDialogSync(remote.getCurrentWindow(), {
    properties: ["openFile", "multiSelections"]
})
if (typeof result === "object") {
    console.log("Selected file paths:")
    console.log(result)
}
```

Both versions can optionally take a BrowserWindow as the first element. If one is provided, the dialog is shown as a modal window.

Check the [Electron dialog documentation](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/dialog) for detailed usage information.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. This doesn't seem to answer the problem. The error still persists:
```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'dialog' before initialization
    at openFileBrowser (renderer.js:37)
    at HTMLLIElement.onclick (proxies.html:16)
```

This doesn't make sense to me as every other module I load and use has no issues. I tried to run this on start up and it worked, it seems to be related to me calling it from a separate html file. Is this normal?